# Swapping three objects in Python. Why is the order relevant?

Tags: python

I want to understand better how the swap of three objects work in Python. I am curious about how the order affects the result when swapping objects and their attributes using the syntax below.

```
left, right, right.attr = right, left.attr, right
```

In particular, I have the following code where I want to reverse a linked list:

```
class Solution(object):                                                            
    def reverseList(self, head):                                                   
        """                                                                        
        :type head: ListNode                                                       
        :rtype: ListNode                                                           
        """                                                                        
        if not head or not head.next: 
            return head                                  

        prev, cur = None, head                                                     
        while cur:
            cur, prev = swap(cur, prev)                                                                                                                                                                      
        return prev
```

I am considering two `swap` functions, each with a different order in which I reassign the objects:

```
def swap_bad(cur, prev):
    prev, cur, cur.next = cur, cur.next, prev 
    return cur, prev
```

and

```
def swap_good(cur, prev):
    cur.next, cur, prev = prev, cur.next, cur
    return cur, prev
```

I would expect both functions to be equivalent, but as the names suggest, the first one does not work, whereas the second one does. Could you shed some light on why that is the case?

Comment: Why not make your life easy and use a temporary variable?

Comment: I need know why. I need know how it works about swap variables in python. I think that must has something useful infomation in it.

Comment: How does the result varies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of the order Python executes the commands.

The setup is the following:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, nxt=None):
        self.name = name
        self.nxt = nxt

    def __str__(self):
        nxt = self.nxt.name if self.nxt is not None else None
        return f"Test(name={self.name}, nxt={nxt})"


prev = Test(0)
cur = Test(1, prev)

def swap_good(cur, prev):
    cur.nxt, cur, prev = prev, cur.nxt, cur

def swap_bad(cur, prev):
    prev, cur, cur.nxt = cur, cur.nxt, prev
```

and indeed the output is different:

```
swap_good(cur, prev)
print(cur)
print(prev)
# Test(name=1, nxt=0)
# Test(name=0, nxt=None)
```

as opposed to

```
# re-initialize cur, prev as above
swap_bad(cur, prev)
print(cur)
print(prev)
# Test(name=1, nxt=0)
# Test(name=0, nxt=0)  # nxt=0 instead of nxt=None
```

disassembling the functions

```
from dis import dis
dis(swap_good)
dis(swap_bad)
```

gives for `swap_good`

```
 20           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (prev)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (cur)
              4 LOAD_ATTR                0 (nxt)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (cur)
              8 ROT_THREE
             10 ROT_TWO
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (cur)
             14 STORE_ATTR               0 (nxt)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (cur)
             18 STORE_FAST               1 (prev)
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

and for `swap_bad`

```
 35           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (cur)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (cur)
              4 LOAD_ATTR                0 (nxt)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (prev)
              8 ROT_THREE
             10 ROT_TWO
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (prev)
             14 STORE_FAST               0 (cur)
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (cur)
             18 STORE_ATTR               0 (nxt)
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see the difference (looking up the [op-codes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions) you can figure out what is really going on here; I was admittedly to lazy to do so but this should get you started).